# Angular doesn't display data on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smartphone

I can't understand why my app works properly only on PC. 
If I open a browser, use mobile version and reload the page it works perfectly.

http://school528.spb.ru/main/admin/new/#/test-list

But if I use smartphones/tablets Angular doesn't display half of my data. 
The data is loaded but is not displayed

Comment: You could use [chromes remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) to investigate this

Comment: Most probably the issue is with css. Try to debug in mobile devices as suggested by @Und3rTow

Comment: I've got only iphone :(